# how to redirect to another page after if condition is satisfied in php?

Tags: php

I have used a php code for redirect to another page, but its not working.I am at loss. please help me. I am giving the code snippet.

```
if($row->cnt==1){
    echo "Succes.";
    // header ('Location:HomePage.php); 
    header("Location:http://localhost/library/HomePage.php");
}
```

Comment: But its not getting redirect to home page.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Warning: Headers already sent" in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/warning-headers-already-sent-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You are already sending content before using the `header` directive.

From the [PHP manul](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

> Remember that `header()` must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with `include`, or `require`,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before `header()` is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

You should remove the `echo` before using `header`.

If you work with a lot of files and are not sure that there is no output before using `header` you should have a look at the [**Output Control Functions**](http://se.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

Answer (score 1):

For a PHP redirect via `header()` call to succede it has to precede any page output, i.e. come before any other header(), print or echo statements. For example this will work.

```
<?php

header("Location: http://someurl.com");
exit;
?>
```

while this will not:

```
<?php
echo "Some text";
header("Location: http://someurl.com");
exit;
?>
```

If you already have output something on the page, you should redirect via Javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://someurl.com";
</script>
```

Comment: where is that `For example this will work.`?

Comment: add `exit();` to the code snippet.