# PHP - using if conditions to redirect to different pages

Tags: php, redirect, if-statement, web, conditional-statements

I want to redirect to different pages on an if condition using php.(not javascript) I tried as the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231254/how-to-redirect-to-onother-page-after-if-condition-is-satified-in-php). But unfortunately it doesn't works for me. :/ Here's my code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            $time_type = $_POST['time_type'];
            $driver_type = $_POST['driver_type'];

            if (strcmp($time_type, "Arrival") && strcmp($driver_type, "Customer") )
            {
                header('location: http://localhost:8080/Project/Enter_Details.html');
                exit();
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This php is linked to a html page below.

```
<html>
    <title> Shopping Complex</title>

    <body>
        <form name = "Type" action = "Type.php" method = "POST">
            <fieldset>
                <table>
                    <p>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type = "radio"
                                   name = "time_type" value = "Arrival">Arrival</input>
                                <input type = "radio"
                                   name = "time_type" value = "Departure">Departure</input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type = "radio"
                                   name = "driver_type" value = "Staff">Staff</input>
                                <input type = "radio"
                                   name = "driver_type" value = "Customer">Customer</input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type = "submit"
                                       value = "Go" id = "buttonId"></input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </p>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </from>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please Help me out of this......

Comment: There is a typo in your program 
`strcmp($diver_type, "Customer")` Change to $driver_type.

Also echo $_POST variables.

Comment: it's `strcmp($driver_type, "Customer")` instead of `strcmp($diver_type, "Customer")`. Next to that, you open the `html` and `body` tag, which is output... dont open those.

Comment: Just a tip, strcmp is a binary comparison, so if evaluate to equal, it'll return 0 and will be cast to false. Otherwise, it'll return 1 (greater than) or -1 (lesser than) if the strings are differents. Both cases will be cast to true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're sending data (HTML tags) before sending the headers (PHP tags)

In order for it to work, make the PHP code the first thing in the document, not any HTML. So change this (also fixed above mentioned $driver_type and missing semicolon mistakes below):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            $time_type = $_POST['time_type'];
            $driver_type = $_POST['driver_type'];

            if (strcmp($time_type, "Arrival") && strcmp($driver_type, "Customer") )
            {
                header('location: http://localhost:8080/Project/Enter_Details.html');
                die;
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

To just this:

```
<?php
    $time_type = $_POST['time_type'];
    $driver_type = $_POST['driver_type'];

    if (strcmp($time_type, "Arrival") && strcmp($driver_type, "Customer") )
    {
        header('location: http://localhost:8080/Project/Enter_Details.html');
        die;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If i not wrong you forgot to give semi colon `;` to your `header()` code

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. Check the PHP code in `Type.php`

Avoid doing any HTML output if you want to output headers (or use output buffering to capture it), specially in this case that is not necessary.

#### 2. Check your HTML code:

This is not valid HTML code:

```
<input type = "radio" name = "time_type" value = "Arrival">Arrival</input>
```

Valid version:

```
<input type = "radio" name = "time_type" value ="Arrival">
```